# Cleanest way to parse duration in Java

Tags: java, jodatime

scala.concurrent.duration package gives one the ability to initialize a duration like so:

```
Duration("5 minutes")
```

I cannot figure out an equivalent in Java that would allow me to do the same easily. Any suggestions (other than using scala from Java?)

Comment: If you look for a non-scala solution but finally want to get a scala-duration then you will also get an extra conversion overhead so maybe you will continue with just scala. I would only choose another library if special features like normalization or internationalization are needed. Keep also in mind that Java-libraries are not primarily written for scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java itself does not handle any duration formatting. You will need 3rd-party-libraries like [Joda-Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) or my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) in order to do what you want.

**Joda-Time (builder-based):**

```
PeriodFormatter pf = 
    new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes")
    .toFormatter();
Period p = pf.parsePeriod("5 minutes");
System.out.println(p); // PT5M
```

**Time4J (pattern-based):**

```
Duration<ClockUnit> d = 
  Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "{m: :en:ONE=minute:OTHER=minutes}")
  .parse("5 minutes");
System.out.println(d); // PT5M
```

However, there are in general following restrictions with such solutions.

- Such procedures are usually only for one language because literals are fixed.
- The inner format structure is often not flexible (input might contain unexpected units).

**My recommendation for storage of a duration:**

You should best use ISO-8601-formats for storage and user-defined formats for representation. This way is language-neutral and flexible for handling several units. Examples:

**Joda-Time with usage of ISO:**

```
Period joda = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("PT5M");
System.out.println(PeriodFormat.wordBased(Locale.ENGLISH).print(joda)); 
// 5 minutes
```

**Time4J with usage of ISO:**

```
Duration<ClockUnit> time4j = Duration.parseClockPeriod("PT5M");
System.out.println(PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(time4j)); 
// 5 minutes
```